# Backbone Collection.fetch() strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Using backbone JS library to build pages.
I have a collection, view and router.
And the goal is to list all the entries of the collection in the page.

The collection

```
window.Artifact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot:"/rest/artifacts",

    initialize:function(){
      this.artifacts = new ArtifactCollection();
    }
});

window.ArtifactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

     model:Artifact,
     url:"/rest/artifacts"

});

var artifacts = new ArtifactCollection;
```

The view

```
window.findView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
       console.log('Initializing Find View');
       this.template = _.template(tpl.get('find'));
    },

    render:function (eventName) {

    var data = { 'data' : artifacts.models };
            $(this.el).html(this.template( data ));
            return this;
    }
});
```

The router program

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes:{
    "":"home",
    "contact":"contact",
    "get":"get",
    "find":"find",
    "requests/:id":"requests"
},

find:function(){

    artifacts.fetch( {
        success:function(){
            this.findView = new findView( );
            this.findView.render();
            $('#content' ).html( this.findView.el );
        }
    });
},
```

The problem is, it works most of the time, but doesn't work sometimes.
It throws the following exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
artifacts.fetch.successmain.js:53
_.extend.fetch.options.successbackbone-0.9.2.js:760
jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery.js:1032
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery.js:1150
donejquery.js:7385
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

Anyone has seen this type of problem before?

Comment: Wait, the artifact model has a collection of artifacts?

Comment: ArtifactCollection is a collection of Artifacts

Comment: thanks for pointing. i should remove it.

Comment: I renamed the `this.findView` to `this.find` in this snippet of code in the Router.   `artifacts.fetch( {
        success:function(){
            this.find = new findView( );
            this.find.render();
            $('#content' ).html( this.find.el );
        }
    });`   Now everything works. Can someone explain what is the significance of this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I renamed the `this.findView` to `this.find` in this snippet of code in the Router. `artifacts.fetch( { success:function(){ this.find = new findView( ); this.find.render(); $('#content' ).html( this.find.el ); } });` Now everything works. Can someone explain what is the significance of this change?

I'm not positive, but I'm guessing that in your `success` function, `this` is a reference to `window`, and when you had `this.findView = new findView();`, you were overwriting `window.findView`, resulting in the "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" when the `success` function runs again and tries to call `new findView()`.